# Pattern for associating pyparsing results with a linked-list of nodes

Tags: python, parsing, design-patterns, linked-list, pyparsing

I have defined a `pyparsing` rule to parse this text into a syntax-tree...

**TEXT COMMANDS:**

```
add Iteration name = "Cisco 10M/half"
    append Observation name = "packet loss 1"
        assign Observation results_text = 0.0
        assign Observation results_bool = True
        append DataPoint
            assign DataPoint metric = txpackets
            assign DataPoint units = packets
        append DataPoint
            assign DataPoint metric = txpackets
            assign DataPoint units = packets
    append Observation name = "packet loss 2"
        append DataPoint
            assign DataPoint metric = txpackets
            assign DataPoint units = packets
        append DataPoint
            assign DataPoint metric = txpackets
            assign DataPoint units = packets
```

**SYNTAX TREE:**

```
['add', 'Iteration', ['name', 'Cisco 10M/half']]
['append', 'Observation', ['name', 'packet loss 1']]
['assign', 'Observation', ['results_text', '0.0']]
['assign', 'Observation', ['results_bool', 'True']]
['append', 'DataPoint']
['assign', 'DataPoint', ['metric', 'txpackets']]
['assign', 'DataPoint', ['units', 'packets']]
...
```

I'm trying to associate all the nested key-value pairs in the syntax-tree above into a linked-list of objects... the heirarchy looks something like this (each word is a `namedtuple`... children in the heirarchy are on the parents' list of children):

```
Log: [ 
    Iteration: [ 
        Observation: 
            [DataPoint, DataPoint], 
        Observation: 
            [DataPoint, DataPoint]
    ]
]
```

The goal of all this is to build a generic test data-acquisition platform to drive the flow of tests against network gear, and record the results.  After the data is in this format, the same data structure will be used to build a test report. To answer the question in the comments below, I chose a linked list because it seemed like the easiest way to sequentially dequeue the information when writing the report.  However, I would rather not assign `Iteration` or `Observation` sequence numbers before finishing the tests... in case we find problems and insert more Observations in the course of conducting the test.  My theory is that the position of each element in the list is sufficient, but I'm willing to change that if it's part of the problem.

The problem is that I'm getting lost trying to assign Key-Values to objects in the linked list after it's built.  For instance, after I insert an `Observation` `namedtuple` into the first `Iteration`, I have trouble reliably handling the update of `assign Observation results_bool = True` in the example above.

Is there a generalized design pattern to handle this situation?   I have googled this for while, but I can't seem to make the link between parsing the text (which I can do) and managing the data-heirarchy (the main problem).  Hyperlinks or small demo code is fine... I just need pointers to get on the right track.

Comment: As for terminology: What you have in the second code block is just the results from parsing. It may be considered a very basic abstract syntax tree. The former block is just the input, source code, etc.

Comment: Could you go into a little detail about why you decided to use a linked-list?  What is the end result you're trying to achieve with this parsed data?

Comment: @jathanism - I think Mike said "linked" but meant "nested" - the data should reflect a hierarchy corresponding to the indentation levels in the input (I'm guessing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up using [textfsm](http://code.google.com/p/textfsm/), which allows me to keep state between different lines while parsing the configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of an actual design pattern for what you're looking for, but I have a great passion for the issue at hand. I work heavily with network devices and parsing and organizing the data is a large ongoing challenge for me.

It's clear that the problem is not parsing the data, but what you do with it afterwards.  This is where you need to think about the meaning you are attaching to the data you have parsed.  The nested-list method might work well for you if the objects containing the lists are also meaningful.

Namedtuples are great for quick-and-dirty class-ish behavior, but they fall flat when you need them to do anything outside of basic attribute access, especially considering that as tuples they are immutable. It seems to me that you'll want to replace certain `namedtuple` objects with full-blown classes.  This way you can highly customize the behavior and methods available.

For example, you know that an `Iteration` will always contain 1 or more `Observation` objects which will then contain 1 or more `DataPoint` objects.  If you can accurately describe the relationships, this sets you on the path to handling them.

Comment: @jathanism... `namedtuples` are only semi-immutable... they have a `_replace()` method that allows you to override values.  I also implemented the child relationships as standard `list()` objects attached to a `namedtuple` attribute.  I have solved a similar problem before - [ciscoconfparse](https://bitbucket.org/mpenning/ciscoconfparse/src/), but it was literally my first foray into python / this kind of parsing (I blasted it out over a weekend after a perl module failed); upon learning more of the language, I know what a hack-job it was.  I want to start fresh, w/ a good design if possible.

Comment: You CAN do that with `namedtuples`, but that's not helping you solve the issue at hand, which still seems to indicate that the meaning and structural use of your parsed output is where your problem lies.